# Rotate quaternion on all 3 axis from axis angle in GLM

Tags: math, opengl, quaternions

I use quaternions for rotations in OpenGL engine.Currently , in order to create rotation matrix for x ,y and z rotations I create a quaternion per axis rotation.Then I multiply these to get the final quaternion:

```
  void RotateTo3(const float xr ,const float yr ,const float zr){

    quat qRotX=angleAxis(xr, X_AXIS); 
    quat qRotY=angleAxis(yr, Y_AXIS);
    quat qRotZ=angleAxis(zr, Z_AXIS);

    quat resQuat=normalize(qRotX * qRotY * qRotZ);
    resQuat=normalize(resQuat);
    _rotMatrix= mat4_cast(resQuat);

 }
```

Now it's all good but I want to create only one quaternion from all 3 axis angles and skip the final multiplication.One of the quat constructors has params for euler angles vector which goes like this:

```
quat resQuat(vec3(yr,xr,zr))
```

So if I try this the final rotation is wrong.(Also tried   quat(vec3(xr,yr,zr)) ) .Isn't there a way in GLM to fill the final quaternion from all 3 axis in one instance ?

**Now , one more thing:**
As Nicol Bolas suggested , I could use glm::eulerAngleYXZ() to fill a rotation matrix right away as by his opinion it is pointless to do the intermediate quaternion step.. But what I found is that the function doesn't work properly , at least for me .For example :

This :

```
          mat4 ex=  eulerAngleX(radians(xr));
      mat4 ey=  eulerAngleY(radians(yr));
      mat4 ez=  eulerAngleZ(radians(zr));

       rotMatrix= ex * ey * ez;
```

Doesn't return the same as this :

```
   rotMatrix= eulerAngleYXZ(radians(yr),radians(xr),radians(zr));
```

And from my comparisons to the correct rotation state ,the first way gives the correct rotations while the second wrong .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
quat formQuaternion(double x, double y, double z, double angle){
     quat out;
     //x, y, and z form a normalized vector which is now the axis of rotation.
     out.w  = cosf( fAngle/2)
     out.x = x * sinf( fAngle/2 )
     out.y = y * sinf( fAngle/2 )
     out.z = z * sinf( fAngle/2 )
     return out;
}
```

Sorry I don't actually know the quat class you are using, but it should still have some way to set the 4 dimensions.  Source: [Quaternion tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html)

Comment: So you say this is they way to use "pure "quaternions?  Like Nicol Bolas hinted above?

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to popular belief, quaternions are not magical "solve the Gimbal lock" devices, such that any uses of quaternions make Euler angles somehow not Euler angles.

Your `RotateTo3` function takes 3 Euler angles and converts them into a rotation matrix. It doesn't matter *how* you perform this process; whether you use 3 matrices, 3 quaternions or [`glm::eulerAngleYXZ`](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.4/a00168.html#gab2c29b80a86caa83f6b550de31e6889f). The result will still be a matrix composed from 3 axial rotations. It will have all of the properties and *failings* of Euler angles. Because it *is* Euler angles.

Using quaternions as intermediaries here is pointless. It gains you nothing; you may as well just use matrices built from successive `glm::rotate` calls.

If you want to do orientation without Gimbal lock or the other Euler angle problems, then you need to [stop representing your orientation as Euler angles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716268/734069).

In answer to the question you actually asked, you can use `glm::eulerAngleYXZ` to compute

Comment: glm::eulerAngleYXZ gives wrong results.That is one of the reasons why I asked the question

Comment: @MichaelIV: What is the "wrong result"? How do you define right and wrong? Euler angles are all based on convention.

Comment: I compare to rotation of solid layers in AfterEffects.So the above example gives me correct rot while using eulerAngleYXZ smth very different... Also ,can you extend on " then you need to stop representing your orientation as Euler angles." ? Do you mean rotate the quaternions directly ?

Answer (score 1):

eulerAngleYXZ gives one possible set of euler angles which, if recombined in the order indicated by the api name, will yield the same orientation as the given quaternion.
It's not a wrong result - it's one of several correct results.

Use a quaternion to store your orientation internally - to rotate it, multiply your orientation quat by another quat representing the amount to rotate by, which can be built from angle/axis to achieve what you want.